# Sql trying to do avg(count)/ count(distinct m)

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

Hey everyone so I have two tables
Tables:

providers table : (2 columns)
id,
name

sessions table: (4 columns)
session_id,
date_of_service,
patient_id,
provider_id

I want to find the avg number of sessions per patient by provider

Would I just do something like

```
select name, avg(count(session_id))/count (distinct patient_id) as avg_sessions
From providers p 
join sessions s 
on  p.id = s.provider_id
Group by name
```

Doesn’t seem to be working

Comment: Perhaps the result you are expecting is an average of sessions `per day` per patient per provider?

Comment: "*Doesn’t seem to be working*" is not a valid Postgres error message.